# Jcarousel change a divs text depending on first item shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with Jcarousel where i need to have a divs text changing when the next button is pressed on the carousel. I have the carousel set up and working how i want, scrolling one item at a time:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.mycarousel').jcarousel({
    scroll : 1
});});
```

```
                <li> <img src="img/slider/slide1.gif" alt="slide1" /></li>
                <li> <img src="img/slider/slide2.gif" alt="slide1" /> /li>
                <li> <img src="img/slider/slide3.gif" alt="slide1" /> /li>
```

Now i want to append the the text inside a div when the next button is pressed i know Jcarousel has the itemFirstInCallback: function but I'm totally lost on how to use this to append a divs text:

```
   <div class="copy">

        <p>

   example text

        </p>


        </div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: Might need some better html markup and a slightly better explanation then you will get a better answer. I'm going bed now, good luck.